# SA in UK require French Schengen

Tags: schengen, transit, uk, france, south-africa

I am a South African currently in the UK (Wales) on a visiting visa. I work on a cruise line that has there embarkation in Monte Carlo (France). My company is stating a Schengen visa to basically get into France to join the ship not even 24hours later. Is it possible that I could apply for this visa in Cardiff at the French embassy (there is one), and what are the chances of it going thru/being successful. I have valid visas for the USA UK with a few outdated pass thru visas such as/for Italy (Schengen), Croatia, Greece. Would any or all of this help my case in getting a short stay visa for Monte Carlo.

Comment: From what i can gather yes

Comment: It is valid for 2 years (this is my second visiting visa for the UK) and i can stay up to 6 months at a time

Comment: so the chances are very strong like 95% i should not any problems and i will get it

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. You'll need to bring all the information about the boat registration, a copy of your contract, your passport and seaman's record book and a copy of each.

Comment: Do you work as a merchant seaman? Do people working as cooks, cleaners, entertainers, etc, on board a cruise ship have a seaman's book?

Answer (score 3):

Based upon what's written, you will *not be successful* in applying for a *Schengen visa*.  This is because your status in the UK is visitor.  Even though your visa has a two year duration, the limit of 6 months does not qualify as a South African who is resident in the UK, and hence the French will refuse your application.

You may be able to qualify for a short-term Seaman's visa...

> Applicants for a seaman’s visa must be employed **in any capacity** on
>   board a vessel, and seeking to enter France solely in pursuit of
>   his/her calling as a seaman, with the intention of departing with the
>   vessel or reshipping on other vessel that is bound for a foreign port
>   or place or one coming to the France to join a vessel in this country.

Source:  [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/index.asp)

These visas are not part of the Schengen treaty and are very limited in terms of duration and mobility.